# Request to spend some time while reviewing suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I noticed while reviewing the suggested edits that some reviewers are in too much of a hurry to collect more number of edits or badges. They can see just two options: "Approve" or "Reject".

This is just an reminder that there are two more options available,
Please take a look on whole post while you are reviewing not only on edited contents and try to make post perfect by using "Improve" option.

For example, consider [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23335998/2)
Three different people reviewed this and approved. No one has seen the unwanted "1. List item" at the end of the post or the unnecessary use or bullet, may be because they just checked the edited content and mark as approved.

Second thing, If you do not have that much time to check whole post or edit, please do not mark that as Rejected or Approved too quickly. You can also use "Skip" option available there.

This is just an effort to improve review standards, You can also notify if I am wrong or missed something.

Any thoughts about how Stack Overflow's reviewing system might address this problem with a feature modification or a policy change?

Comment: The types of reviewers who do the things you're trying to discourage are the types of people that don't read meta posts.

Comment: This is a good point, but it's not a question. Do you have any suggestions about what SO can do about editors that are reviewing too quickly?  For example, I really think something like this should be posted when one is reviewing.

Comment: This is not a question, But it is a discussion I think :) Where people can post their views and suggestion also.

Comment: Added the last paragraph to the post, turning it into what would seem to be the forum-relevant question.  Kishan just change it if that isn't what you meant.

Comment: @La-comadreja That seems a valid one :)